# How to (quickly) convert float to Byte?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that processes all the pixels in a bitmap (represented as a `Byte` array). For each pixel, I do fairly complex calculations for each R, G and B value using a `float` to store the calculated value until finally converting it back to a `Byte` (using just a cast, and I'm certain the value in the `float` will always be 255.0 or less).

In trying to optimize this method, I was surprised to find that about 80% of the overall processing time was from just the casting of the three `float` values for R, G and B to their `Byte` counterparts.

Is there any kind of super-fast way of doing this (e.g.):

```
float Rtotal = 123.7;
float Gtotal = 7.3;
float Btotal = 221.3;

Byte Rsource = (Byte)Rtotal;
Byte Gsource = (Byte)Gtotal;
Byte Bsource = (Byte)Btotal;
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is a bit odd. If I just make this change:

```
float Rtotal = 123.7;
float Gtotal = 7.3;
float Btotal = 221.3;

Byte Rsource = (int)Rtotal;
Byte Gsource = (int)Gtotal;
Byte Bsource = (int)Btotal;
```

the extra time caused by the cast to `(Byte)` disappears. My guess here is that the compiler is adding some kind of bounds checking to the `(Byte)` cast to ensure that it's within the valid range of a Byte, whereas it omits this if the cast is to `int`.